# Environment variables in Azure WebJob with Django

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a Django project in Azure WebApp. The project's settings are configured with environment variables, for example:

[image]

And the settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': os.getenv("POSTGRES_DB"),  
        'USER': os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWOR), 
        'HOST': os.getenv("POSTGRES_HOST"),  
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the project have a WebJob that runs a Django command:

```
app_data
 |--jobs
     |--triggered
         |--my_webjob
             |--run.py
             |--settings.job
```

The script of the WebJob, run.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\Lib\\site-packages")
sys.path.append(r"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot")
import django
from django.core.management import call_command


django.setup()
call_command('my_webjob')
```

And my command "my_webjob" try to do some stuffs, but **don't get the environment variables of the WebApp**, 
if i print the environment, this is the result:

my_webjob.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print "================="
        print "DEBUG: ENVS"
        print "================="
        print "POSTGRES_USER:"
        print os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER", "")
        print "---------------"
        print "POSTGRES_DB:"
        print os.getenv("POSTGRES_DB", "")
```

The output when the WebJob have been running:

```
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] =================
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] DEBUG: ENVS
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] =================
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] POSTGRES_USER:
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] 
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] ---------------
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO] POSTGRES:
[04/29/2016 08:32:51 > 5d941a: INFO]
```

The WebApp and the WebJobs works correctly except with this problem.
A easy solution is write my environment variables in a file and read it in the webjobs, but i need that all my passwords, urls... are stored in environments variables,

How can i share these environment variables between the project and the WebJobs?

Comment: Hi @Avara, any updates yet?

Comment: It's works now. It's very weird because I've not changed anything. Maybe, the first time I had deployed, the webapp updated itself with delay. I'm working to confirm this. Thanks @GaryLiu-MSFT :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my side. And do you have got any error message from the Azure Web Job's output logs?

Here are my test scripts for your information:

The **WebJob.py** (As I used the Azure Django template to build the test environment. Which just with default configurations):

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(r"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\Lib\\site-packages")
sys.path.append(r"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot")
import django
from django.core.management import call_command

os.environ.setdefault(
        "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
        "DjangoWebProject.settings"
    )

django.setup()
call_command('my_webjob')
```

The **my_webjob.py**:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import os
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print "================="
        print "DEBUG: ENVS"
        print "================="
        print "SOME_CUSTOM_SETTINGS:"
        print os.getenv("SOME_CUSTOM_SETTINGS", "")
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.